# cloning a bitbucket project in AndroidStudio

Tags: git, android-studio, version-control, bitbucket

I try to clone a project from Bitbucket into Android Studio. The project was originally published from Eclipse.

But I get the error:

> Clone failed. Failed to start Git process.

What I have done so far:

1. Installed a Bitbucket plugin: https://bitbucket.org/dmitry_cherkas/jetbrains-bitbucket-connector/downloads (http://www.goprogramming.space/connecting-android-studio-project-with-bitbucket/)
2. Then VCS -> checkout from Version Control -> Bitbucket

I get a login screen.
I logged into Bitbucket and I could see the list of my projects (WOW!)
Then selecting a project and press ok. -> *Clone failed. Failed to start Git process.*

Any help on how I can clone a Bitbucket repository?

Comment: Check this link to clone android project from BitBucket:-

http://www.learnwithmindscript.in/blog/user/blog_details/3

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The 3rd party for bitbucket plugin on android studio seems not work. You can try below steps to clone a bitbucket repo:

VCS -> Git -> clone -> paste bitbucket URL repo -> clone.

It can clone successfully.

Comment: If you face the authentication error, create a password at https://bitbucket.org/account/settings/app-passwords/. I thought it is my account pass but it is not, it should be app pass.

Answer (score 5):

Go to repository in BitBucket 
to the top right there is button called **Clone**
Click on it copy the link

Now go to android studio 
Click >**VCS**>**CheckOutFromVersionControl**>**Git**
Now paste the link remove the git clone at the start of the **link**
Click Okay

Answer (score 1):

For using BitBucket plugin you need to install git on your system too.

Install git on Linux using following command in terminal:

> sudo apt-get install git

Windows & Mac OS X:

> [git tutorial | Install git](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/install-git)

Answer (score 1):

For cloning project from BitBucket we should have git software in our system.

Then Go to your destination folder --> right click and select "Git Bash Here"

It will open the command prompt --> here you can type as "git clone your source path".

The above steps are worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Below answer may help to someone.

I cloned my project from Bitbucket to Android studio old version. It was working fine. But when I update my Android studio to Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch 3, I faced lot of issues. I unable to pull, commit & push.

I plan to do new clone. I unable to clone, I got Clone failed error messages. Then I figured out the issue.

**First tried with HTTPS clone, it was not working. Next time I tried with SSH clone, it was working fine.**

So please check with SSH way. You can get it.